# how to delete a row after update in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

I have a table named "notification" that has 3 columns, id, number and link. I want to create a trigger that when the "number" column updated and got 0, row to be deleted.
how can I create the trigger for that in phpmyadmin? what should I write in definition of trigger in phpmyadmin?
thanks

Comment: I have a nagging feeling that any attempt to use a trigger for this will just result in an ERROR 1442, but I'd be happy if someone proves me wrong.

Comment: Mureinik is right. You cannot do this in a trigger (with MySQL). But you could just treat "0" as "deleted" and filter such rows out (so e.g. use "where number > 0" whenever you read from that table). You can clean up the table regularly (e.g. with an event) and delete every row with `number = 0`, if you fear your table gets to big.